# IB_DESIGNABLE draw image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ibdesignable

I've created a simple view that will show some AVPlayer content, or if this does not exist (initial state) draw a splash image.

I've added the IB_DESIGNABLE directive, and am drawing the splash image in drawRect. However, in Interface Builder, the component renders as a black square. I'd like it to draw the image. Is this possible?

At runtime all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To investigate what goes on within the IB rendition for your `drawRect:` implementation, I would recommend to debug how your view behaves with IB using the debugger.
For that, select your view in IB, and then use the `Debug Selected Views` item from the `Editor` menu in XCode. By setting up a breakpoint in the `drawRect:` you should be able to understand what's going on and why you get a black square.

Comment: I'd solved this but forgot I had asked on SO. Turned out the image was nil during IB's pass at drawRect. Setting the image via IB helped. Useful info all the same

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, you can set custom variables in IB (such as your images) using the keyword `IBInspectable`, f.e. as:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface MyCustomControl : UIView
{
    IBInspectable UIImage *myImage;
    ...
}
...
@end
```

For more info read this [awesome blog](http://blog.otaviocc.com/blog/2014/09/18/ib-designable-and-inspectable) where I found that keyword (I had been looking for something like that for quite a while).